# Firebase Dynamic links

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links, swift4.2

I have implemented a firebase dynamic link to an IOS app. The ink is generating but I want to shorten the link in order to share with social media. But I couldn't proceed with generating a shorter link. The following is the code I'm using for to generate the short link.

```
    //2. Or create a shortened dynamic link
    components?.shorten { (shortURL, warnings, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // TODO: Handle shortURL.
        print("shortURL is \(String(describing: shortURL))")
    }
```

But every time it's ended up with the following error which is "error is The operation couldn’t be completed. Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link:". Therefore how to short the long link.

Comment: Is your device/simulator connected to the internet? Short link generation needs call to google servers.

Comment: Yes there is no any connection issue

Comment: According to the error, it sounds like you're trying to shorten a link that's already shortened. What does your components object look like?

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared the sample code which shorten the long link, hope may help you :-

```
        guard let link = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/77/whats-new-in-swift-4-2") else { return }
        let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "https://xyz.page.link" //Your URL prefix added in Dynamic Links section on Firebase
        let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix)
        linkBuilder?.shorten(completion: { (url, warnings, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
           print("The short URL is: \(String(describing: url!))")
        })
```